# Cannot retrieve Entity Framework Object Context for Verification in SimpleInjectorInitializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

It seems that when I installed the Simple Injector MVC3 Integration package, SimpleInjectorInitializer was placed in the App_Start folder. However, when the Verify() method is called within Initialize(), it produces this error when attempting to get the Entity Framework Object Context (I have also provided the inner exceptions):

```
The supplied connection string is not valid, because it contains insufficient mapping or metadata information.
    InnerException: Unable to determine application context. The ASP.NET application path could not be resolved.
        InnerException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
            InnerException: (Shown in browser) This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.
```

It also seemed that I had to move the registration calls from the Global.asax.cs Application_Start() to the SimpleInjectorInitializer's InitializeContainer() method.

I am not entirely sure what to do at this point, but this issue seems somewhat related to this question: [Connection string exception after upgrading to Ninject 3.0.0-rc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267065/connection-string-exception-after-upgrading-to-ninject-3-0-0-rc3/)

It seems that the application is trying to load the context before Entity Framework is even aware of its own and is unable to properly parse the connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that the application is trying to load the context before
>   Entity Framework is even aware of its own and is unable to properly
>   parse the connection string?

You are absolutely right. The `SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize` method is called automatically during the pre application start phase. Although there is no problem configuring the container at this point, in your situation it's too early for `Verify()` to be called. `Verify` simply iterates all registrations and calls `GetInstance` on them to see whether it can create it. At that point in the application's lifetime however, an Entity Framework object context can't be created. I must say I think it is weird that EF framework knows anything about the ASP.NET framework, but unfortunately that's the way it is.

To solve this problem, you can either move the `Verify()` call, or the complete initialization to a later moment in the application startup. For instance, you can do the following:

1. Remove the `[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod]` (top line) of the **SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs** class.
2. Add a call to the `SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize()` method in the `Application_Start()` event of the global asax.

After doing this, initializing (and especially, verifying) of the object graph is done *after* the pre-init state.

Another option is to remove the `container.Verify();` call from the `SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize` method, since it is the early verification process that is killing you. However, please read this [Verify the container’s configuration](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Verifying_Configuration) first, to see alternatives, before doing so.

The SimpleInjector.MVC NuGet package uses the `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod` for convenience. It allows the package to 'just work', without a need for a developer to do any manual coding (except of course wiring the container) to get this working. But since this doesn't work when working with Entity Framework, we will have to reconsider this strategy.

Comment: Thanks, Steven! I will definitely give that a read before deciding what the best course of action might be on my end. I hope that you will be able to find a solution for future iterations. Also, is there a more direct way to contact you if any other problems are to arise? Oh, and my secondary question was whether the registration calls should indeed be moved into the InitializeContainer() method, as the examples show them in the Application_Start() in the Global.asax.